# Wrong behaviour with Mui v4 textfield and string validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a validation on a mui text field

```
<TextField
                        name={`persona/${deiValue._id}/${data.indicator}`}
                        value={deiValue.value || ''}
                        variant="outlined"
                        placeholder="Add"
                        disabled={mode.value !== LAYOUT_CONSTANTS.MODE.EDIT.value}
                        inputProps={{
                          'aria-label': 'persona'
                        }}
                        InputProps={{
                          classes: {
                            input: classes.inputStyles
                          },
                          endAdornment: (
                            <InputAdornment position="end" disableTypography={true}>
                              <Typography variant="body2">%</Typography>
                            </InputAdornment>
                          )
                        }}
                        onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e, deiValue._id)}
                        onInput={e => {
                          if (!validateNumberFieldWDecimals(e.target.value)) {
                            console.log("false")
                            e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.value.length - 1);
                          }
                        }}
                      />
```

And the i have the validateNumberFieldWDecimals I run onInput, also tried logging all the values, ("22." === input) gives true, both have type of string even tried to copy it with a string template but the regex keeps giving false when I add the first decimal

```
  const stringInput = `${input}`
  if (input === "") return true;
  const regex = /^(?!.*e)(\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?|100(\.0{1,2})?)$/;
  const result = regex.test(stringInput)
  console.log("22.");
  console.log(stringInput);
  console.log("22." === input);
  console.log(regex.test("22.2"), 'hand');
  console.log(regex.test(stringInput), 'inputvalue');
  return result;
}
```